# WordPress Custom URL with Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, url

now i want to use standard url Like http://localhost/websitename/categoryname/
while passing value in href, in wordpress
Hi i have two table one is category and another is product in admin panel
i insert category and sub category and insert product according to category.
in front-end i displaying subcategory under category and now want when anyone click 
on subcategory it will redirect in to next page such as 
http://localhost/websitename/categoryname
in this page display all product under particular category.
Right now using ?id=125 and aacording to this particlar category id product are 
displaying 
how can i cahnge url

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-> Permalinks and then custom, paste this:

```
/%postname%/
```

Comment: Hi Ryan I have lot's of category like any shopping website

Comment: how many url i will post there i have 12 category and under near 25 subcategory

Comment: It will go automatic, just add %postname%/

Comment: Hi Ryan I want to tell one more thing i have a product page in which i paste my short-code fetching category data and in href of category name i am redirecting in next page where i am fetching all product according to category id.